# Extending class in a singleton object

Tags: scala, class, object, singleton

I wrote this example and was pretty wondered:

```
class TestMatch(val i: Int)

object TestMatch extends TestMatch(10){ // <-- Here
  def apply(i: Int) = new TestMatch(i)
  def unapply(tm : TestMatch): Option[Int] = Some(tm.i)
}
```

What's going on here? We extend `TestMatch(10)`. How can we extend an instance f test match created with `i = 10`? It doesn't make much sense to me. Or `TestMatch(val i: Int)` defines a ***set of types*** instead of a single type. Like template in C++:

```
template<int i>
class TestMatch{
   //...
}
```

I was consufed by the line object

TestMatch extends ***TestMatch(10)***

It looks like we extend `TestMatch(10)` which I thought was an object of type `TestMatch` created with a construcotr parameter `i = 10`. If I wrote

```
TestMatch extends TestMatch
```

it would not compile.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It's not clear what you want explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not extending an instance of TestMatch class. The below syntax just  passes in constructor parameters to the base class.

```
 object TestMatch extends TestMatch(10)
```

Comment: What does it mean? So we actually extends TestMatch, but also tell the compiler to pass 10 during when creating the singleton object. Correct?